# Java terminates at an if statement, exit value 0

Tags: java, bufferedreader, terminate, filewriter, stringreader

I have a program that reads in lines from a file (with two lines) using a while loop (condition is `bufferedReader.readLine()!=null`), assigns `myJSONObject` a JSON read from the file, then I have an if statment (`if(bufferedReader.readLine()!=null&&!bufferedReader.readline.matches(DELETE_REGEX))` and if that's true (i.e. if the line we read is not null, and we don't match a regex) then perform some function on the JSON which should append that new JSON to a file.

I have this in some try-catch blocks. It looks a little like so:

```
try{
    openFiles;
    while(buff.readLine()!=null){
          try {
              instatiateAndUseJSONParser;
              if(bufferedReader.readLine()!=null
                    &&!bufferedReader.readline.matches(DELETE_REGEX)) 
              {doSomeStuff;}
              else
              {continue;}
          } catch (AllTheExceptions e){e.printStackTrace}
     }
     closeFiles;
}catch(SomeMoreExceptions e){e.printStackTrace}
```

When I run this is gets to the iff statement, and then terminates with exit value:0 (program closed as normal)

Why is this? It doesn't get anywhere near the 'continue' or a catch block.

If I remove the second line I get a NullPointerException due to line 50 of String Reader, but I'm not using `StringReader` (I've tried importing it, but eclipse yellow-underlines it and this changes nothing). When debugging, it pops up a tab for `StringReader.<init>(String) line: 50` and just says 'Source not found'.

I'm pretty new to Java, so I don't really have a clue what's happening. Any help would be appreciated in clearing this up.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think we can give you an accurate answer unless you prost the real code ... or an SSCE that behaves the same way as the real code.

Comment: `When I run this is gets to the iff statement, and then terminates with exit value:0 (program closed as normal)`... This is not a plausible explanation of what is happening. However, the code you posted is (most likely) sufficiently different from the real code that we can't give you an accurate explanation of what is really happening, and what is causing it.

Comment: @StephenC my internet machien and coding machine are seperate so making an SSCE is not as easy as it could be...Still I think JB fixed that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time `readLine()` is called, it reads a new line. You can thus read 3 lines per iteration in your current code. You should assign the result of the first call to a variable, and use this variable:

```
String line = null;
while ((line = buff.readLine()) !=null) {
    try {
        instatiateAndUseJSONParser;
        if (line.matches(DELETE_REGEX)) {
            doSomeStuff;
        }
    } 
    catch (AllTheExceptions e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

You should also avoid swallowing exceptions.

Comment: Brilliant I'll give this a go.

Comment: This fixes that bug, but I have another that I'll tackle separately. Any idea why it would terminate, then throw and exception depending on the read-from-file?

Comment: No. You don't provide the real code, you don't provide the file, and you don't provide the exception stack trace. I don't have any crystal ball.

Comment: That's fair enough, I was wondering if this sort of behaviour was a clear sign of something specific. Thanks anyway!